# How to custom render a ZF2 Collection with matching fieldset

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've created a standard application using collections to map one to many relationships (without using Doctrine) pretty much the way it is being described in http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html and I have something like the following code:

```
class Person {
  protected $attrributes;
} 

class Attribute {
  protected $attr1;
  protected $attr2;
}
```

I've created the `AttributeFieldset` and the matching `AttributeForm` required and I've added the `AttributeFieldset` on my `PersonForm`:

```
$this->add(
  array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'attributes',
    'options' => array(
      'label' => _("Add person attribute"),
      'count' => 1,
      'should_create_template' => true,
      'allow_add' => true,
      'target_element' => array(
        'type' => 'Persons\Form\AttributesFormFieldset'
      )
    )
  ));
```

Calling the `$this->formCollection()` view helper will generate the default HTML for the collection and the data template to add new attributes dynamically via javascript as specified in the documentation.

However what I would like to accomplish is to have a table listing with all the existing attributes of the person, with an edit/delete option and create a modal window with the collection fieldset to add new attributes to the Person.

Imagine the following html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="add(this); return false;">Add new attribute</a>
<table>
  <? foreach( $this->person->attributes as $attribute ): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $attribute['attr1']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="edit(this); return false">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="delete(this); return false">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I know I can skip the formCollection entirely and add `<input type="hidden">` tags the way ZF2 Collection would expect them (e.g. `attribute[0][attr1]` etc) on each row I add to my table and have the form created dynamically but I am guessing that I will be missing out on the ZF2 InputFilters.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Has anyone done it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Collections and requiring custom Markup is annoying. But it's not difficult:

```
$collections = $form->get('collection-element');
echo '<table>'
// render thead and tbody open if needed
foreach ($collections as $col) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->formInput($col->get('input-from-collection-name'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->formInput($col->get('other-input-from-collection-name'); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;
echo '</table>';
```

It is as simple as that. It's just annoying. Furthermore going by the default examples within configuration: the easiest way to add a `template` for additional elements is to just render the form once, then copy the generated HTML and then just paste this into your data-template.

Comment: You are probably right, although FormCollection provides us with a great functionality it can really be a pain in the ass.. I thought of having the template static also, yet it loses all the benefit of having to change only the fieldset in case of a change in the underline database

Comment: Hello Sam, is there any way to passing template argument? coz i cannot able to find the created template. which I need to use to create additional fields like here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically

Comment: @MyselfMalay sadly there is no such thing. In these scenarios I still find myself to simply overwrite the default FormRow / FormSelect / FormInput helpers. That way the Fieldset rendering usually works out for me. An alternative would be to use FormSelect/FormInput, etc.. without formRow and then add the template tag yourself with the custom HTML from your fieldset... it's annoying but that's just what web-forms are :'(

Comment: so basically this is not supported, I'm using boostrap, and can't able to add class e.g. **form-input** for the input element. I did spend 2 days with it, but no luck. Now, is there any way to get the generated template in your custom process ..?

Comment: @MyselfMalay adding css classes shouldn't be a problem at all as they belong into the `attributes` configuration array of your form elements. Furthermore there's numerous Twitter Bootstrap solution modules out there.